# Jump to route without loosing data from current Observable

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7, angular2-observables

I'm a little confused on how to do this.  I keep losing any changes I make.  I have this as my route navigation declaration:

```
const route: Routes = [
...

    {
        path: 'configs',
        redirectTo: 'configs/entry1'
    },
    {
        path: 'configs/:name',
        component: configPageComponent
    }
...
```

I navigate fine, but when I jump between names, I loose the data that I have edited in the material form of:

```
<div id="infoDiv">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput id="settingsSearch" placeholder="Search">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel #panel_{{databaseName}} expanded="true" hideToggle="true" (click)="changeSetting(this, $event)">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title class="tableTitle">
          <span style="display: flex; align-items: top;" class="{{arrowClass}}">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="30"
                  height="30"
                  viewBox="0 0 30 20">
              <path d = "M3 3 L3 17 L20 10 z" stroke = "#3e6487" stroke-width = "2" fill = "#5b9bd5"/>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span style="display: flex; align-items: center;" class="settingName">{{databaseName}}&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</span>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;" *ngFor="let settingValues of dbSettings | async; let index = index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <span class="propertyKey" id="settingValues.configName">{{settingValues.configurationName}}</span>
        <mat-form-field class="propertyValue">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="settingValues.configValue" id="{{settingValues.configValue}}">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

I can edit the input fields, but when I switch to another entry in this list:

```
<div id="configList">
  <h1>Services:</h1>
  <mat-list>
    <h3 matSubheader><span class="healthIconDiv">Health</span><span class="nameDiv">Service</span></h3>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let listEntry of dbList | async; last as last">
      <div class="healthIconDiv">
        <div class="healthIcon">TBD</div>
      </div>
      <a routerLink="/config/{{listEntry}}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nameDiv listName">{{listEntry}}</a>
      <mat-divider [inset]="true" *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
  <div class="healthIconDiv">
    <div class="healthIcon  goodHealth"></div><div class="healthStatus">Healthy</div>
  </div>
  <div class="healthIconDiv">
    <div class="healthIcon  badHealth"></div><div class="healthStatus">Poor Health</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I loose what I edited.  How can I keep the data I have edited, when I switch to another db's data config?

This may help:

page: https://angular-w6bzvw.stackblitz.io/configuration

edit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6bzvw

Comment: OK, I seem to be misunderstanding Observables.  I'll admit that, after reading this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798236/angular2-how-to-update-an-item-inside-an-observable-collection

I'm still not exactly sure how to get the Observable into a Subject, or at least haven't played with it yet.  Any advice?

Comment: The title says Angular 2 but you tagged this as Angular 7 so which one is it?

Comment: It's Angular 2.7

Comment: angular 2.7 does not exist https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Angular 7 is Angular 2 edition 7.  Sure you can say Angular is not AngularJS, or Angular 1, but all Angular, that's not AngularJS, is Angular 2, just anther edition of Angular 2.  Dumb thing to debate, but go ahead if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everybody.  I think this might help other people, if they are having trouble like this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wthbaq

It's a half decent solution I came up with, with some help of a colleague.